# grammar in a specific sentence

Tags: grammar

With the following sentence:

> **自分の唾液を入れたポリ袋を**女子高校生の背中に**投げ付けた*として***、警視庁田無署は６日までに、暴行の疑いで埼玉県新座市野寺、派遣社員工藤清哉容疑者（４１）を逮捕した。

- Does `自分の唾液を入れた` modify `ポリ袋`?
- Does it make sense?
- Is `ポリ袋` the object of the verb `投げ付けた`?
- What does `として` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Does 自分の唾液を入れた modify ポリ袋?

Yes.

(2) Does it make sense?

Yes.

(3) Is ポリ袋 the object of the verb 投げ付けた?

Yes.

(4) What does として mean?

'As of', 'for', 'claiming that'. I.e., 'arrested for throwing ...'

Translation is:

> **Claiming him to have** thrown a polyethylene bag containing his own saliva to the back of a female high school student, Tanashi police station of the Metropolitan Police Department arrested the suspect 工藤清哉, temporary technician and **resident of** 埼玉県新座市野寺, **by** the sixth day **for** the suspicion of assault.

Comment: How to translate this sentence?

Comment: @Steven What is your try?

Comment: Because of throwing a polyethylene bag containing his own saliva to the back of a female high school student, 警視庁田無署arrested 派遣社員工藤清哉容疑者 at 埼玉県新座市野寺 on ６日 because of suspecting of his assault.