# Meaning of させたとして

Tags: grammar, causation

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3PjMB2mZ390) news I heard this sentence:

> 福岡県飯塚市のディスカウントストアで食料品を万引きし、店の警備員にけがを**させたとして**隣接する嘉麻市の職員の男が逮捕されました。

I can understand the meaning form the context, but the part させたとして isn't that clear to me: I know させる is causative, which means that the recipient is forced or allowed to do an action; and I know として either as "as, in the capacity of", or as て-form of とする, "to try/decide to do" (and [several](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B) other meaning.

In that sentence... I'm not so sure about its meaning. The sentence means that the suspect injured the guard, but why the causative? Because she is forced to take on an injury? And why として?

Comment: Possible duplicate for として: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/4926/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11230/9831

Comment: Good finding; I'd say it's a duplicate for として, but I'd say no for けがをされた.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly a difficulty might be that there is no real equivalent of けがをする in English.

警備員**が**けがをする means *A guard got injured*. But note that in Japanese, it is an ordinary active sentence. On the other hand 警備員**に**けがをさせる means *(Someone) injured a guard*. So to think in the opposite direction, *injure* (or *hurt*) only translates as a causative けがをさせる in Japanese (at least when it involves physical injury).

として here only means *as*.

Overall, the sentence would translate: *A man was arrested as having shoplifted in a discount store... and injured a guard of the shop*.

Comment: How would you translate "A guard injured someone"?

Comment: It is 警備員**が** （誰かに）けがをさせる.

Comment: I guess the equivalent of けがをする is "to receive an injury." Then 警備員がけがをする means "the guard received an injury." And 警備員にけがをさせる means "someone made the guard receive an injury" or more idiomatically "someone injured the guard."