# Understanding verb+などとして

Tags: grammar

> 日本格付研究所（ＪＣＲ）は、企業によるＥＳＧ（環境・社会・企業統治）対応が社債の格付けに与えるプラス、マイナス両面の影響度を可視化し、情報提供を始めた。気候変動、生物多様性などの項目ごとにそれぞれ３段階のスコアで示す。ＥＳＧ投資への関心が高まる中、関連情報の発信を強化し、投資家に幅広く活用してもらう狙い。
>
> 具体的には、温室効果ガス抑制への貢献度が高い水素や風力発電事業を展開する企業の場合には、収益力が高まる**などとして**、現在か将来の格付けに一定のプラスに働く可能性があることを明示する。一方で環境対応による投資負担や調達コスト上昇などマイナス要因も分析した。

Can I understand the bold part this way?
The など is a nominalizer, just like の or こと and this として just means "as".

Or should I treat などとして as a set phrase, as is explained in [this link](https://learnjapanesedaily.com/japanese-grammar-%E3%82%84%E3%81%AA%E3%81%A9-yanado.html)?

Comment: Related https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/90189/45489

Answer (score 2, accepted):

など may be almost nominalizing, but it is a particle grammatically. It means *etc.*

として is a little tricky. It can be considered *as*, but probably it would be helpful to think it means *saying that* or *citing as a reason that* (+ since *as* can be used for a reason, it can be translated sometimes into *as*).

- 彼は5年前窃盗を犯したとして逮捕された He was arrested *for* having committed a theft 5 years ago.
- 政府は感染者が急増しているとして自粛を呼びかけた The government asked for stay-at-home, saying (as a reason) that the number of infections is growing rapidly.

So the passage literally says, though a bit ambiguous,

> Concretely, in case of those companies developing 温室効果ガス抑制への貢献度が高い水素や風力発電事業, **saying that profitability increases** (by such developments) **and for other reasons**, JCR will explicitly mention rating will be favored for those companies.

To clarify, など indicates there may be other reasons than profitability for working on renewable energies favoring credit ratings.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the sentence, mainly the part after として: ...現在か将来(present or future)の格付け(rating)に(marks the receiver)一定のプラス(certain gain)に働く(work)可能性(chance)があることを明示する(explicitly state). To me it sounds like, "[JCR] will explicitly state that there's a chance that present or future rating will receive a certain gain." Can you possibly correct me? I don't exactly understand your translation and can't say I'm satisfied with mine.

Comment: @x-yuri Your translation should be fine (and I don't think it differs too much from mine in the answer). Essentially it paraphrases 企業によるＥＳＧ（環境・社会・企業統治）対応が社債の格付けに与えるプラス、マイナス両面の影響度を可視化し. That is, (By providing a certain index devised for the objective of 可視化) JCR will make explicit the chance/possibility of (those investments in ESG) affecting positively the present/future valuation of those companies (investing in ESG).

Comment: The reason I was confused is likely the lack of the word "chance" or "possibility" in your translation. | So you're saying that in this case として simply plays the role of "and," connecting the 2 clauses (the second one goes till the end of the sentence)? "...[JCR will say] that profitability increases [for the above] and other reasons, and [JCR] will make explicit the chance/possibility that the present/future rating [of the companies] will rise." Is there no connotation suggested by として as in your previous examples (reason)?...

Comment: ...I'm using "will say" because I guess its tense should match that of "will make explicit." | Can you possibly expand on the "companies developing ..." part? Seeing 展開する企業 it makes sense that what's on the left describes what the companies develop. But there's が there. Is it a subject marker in this case? I fail to come up with a sensible translation for the part you left untranslated. Developing what exactly?

Comment: @x-yuri Think about 温室効果ガス抑制への貢献度が高い水素や風力発電事業を展開する企業の場合には、収益力が高まるとして without など which just suggests other reasons than *profitability increases*. Xの場合には as a whole works adverbially *In case of companies that develop...* The objects of 展開する are 水素 and 風力発電事業 and these two are modified by  a relative clause 温室効果ガス抑制への貢献度が高い. From where the clause encapsulated by として starts is ambiguous (but I don't think it matters a lot), I just translated as I see it, but may be it is better to translate it to *Saying that, in case of companies that develop..., profitability increases, ....*

Comment: To summarize, it becomes: *saying that profitability increases for the companies that develop hydrogen and wind power whose contributability towards suppression of greenhouse gases is high and (saying/mentioning) for other reasons, JCR will make explicit...*

Comment: Maybe you can look at this though the OP does not have を.  After all として is just a way to quote, など adds some vagueness to it. [Meaning of ~を~に(して) / ~を~として / ~を~にする / ~を~とする / ~を~にした / ~を~とした](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/73082)